# Running kmeans function on matrix with NaN?

Tags: matlab, nan, k-means

I have a 161X911 data matrix of 0,1,2's and then there are some NaN's throughout the matrix. I try and run the built in function kmeans on the data and whenever I have a K(number of clusters) value greater than 5 it returns this

```
Warning: Ignoring rows of X with missing data. 
> In kmeans at 128
??? Error using ==> kmeans at 284
X must have more rows than the number of clusters.
```

Is there a way around this? I guess only 5 rows do not have any NaN's in them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This heart of this question goes beyond a simple programming question about `NaN`s.  It's a more fundamental question about clustering in the presence of missing data.

Here are some links showing examples of what do in these cases.  Which method is best depends on your circumstances.

1. [Paper showing nearly exactly what you want to do.](http://www.litech.org/~wkiri/Papers/wagstaff-missing-ifcs04.pdf)
2. [Code projects on Google code](http://code.google.com/p/noolabsimplecluster/)
3. [Another paper in an IEEE Journal](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2225897)

Comment: I just noticed that the third link was broken. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use K-Means, you're going to have to put numbers in those not-a-number places. One way to do it would be to, for each column, take the mean of the non-NaN values and replace the NaNs in that column with that value.